# how to detect not in trained-for-category images when using resnet50

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tf.keras, transfer-learning, image-classification

I have trained resnet50 on four categories of images.  It works fantastic when I feed it an image in any one of the four categories -- I have essentially 100% accuracy on images in these categories.

However, when I feed my trained Resnet50 model an image of a similar object, but not in one of the original four categories, the prediction comes back as one of the four existing classes.  By this I mean, in the array that is returned with the likelihood of each category, in many cases the likelihood of one of the categories is basically 1.  For example, when I query the model about image that is **not** in one of the four categories, the prediction array will look like

[1.3492944e-07 9.9999988e-01 8.3132584e-14 1.4716975e-24]

Here is the prediction array for an image that the model **was** trained on:

[1.8217645e-27 1.0000000e+00 3.6731971e-32 0.0000000e+00]

These scores are different, but not much different.  Many of the images that are not in one of the trained-for categories have a 1.00000000 for one of the labels.

I had been planning on dealing with the oddball images by looking at the prediction array to see if the max(category labels prediction) was below some threshold.  But most of my max(category labels predictions) are all above .99999 and so I can't differentiate between images in the training set and images not part of the training set.

I plan to train my model for N buckets.  When I am running the system I will occasionally have images that are not in one of the N buckets and I need to know that.  I don't care what they are, I just want to know when an image is not in one of the N buckets.

Resnet50 does a great job of forcing everything into one of the categories, even when it is not.

My images are super well defined!  I wonder if I am somehow overtraining or overlooking some other obvious error.

Here is an example of an image that was correctly categorized:

[in training set and correctly categorized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2qiS.png)

Here is an image that is not part of the training set that was then categorized into one of the categories:

[not in training set and incorrectly categorized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dy8X.png)

In summary: I am trying to sort images and I need to know when one of the images is not part of the training categories so I can reject that image.  Restated, I want to sort images into buckets:  known, trained for buckets, and one unknown bucket.

Is there any way to do this?
Should I use a different classifier than Resnet50?

My images are grayscale, bicubic interpolated during resize (large to smaller), 150x150. I have about 1,600 training images and 200 validation images per category.   My accuracy and val_accuracy are .9997 after 3 epochs.

[Training and validation accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92ggU.png)

[Training and validation loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjjUl.png)

Comment: This is not a programming problem, please search for out of distribution detection, that is the task you are attempting.

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry I didn't post in the right place.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your model only knows about 4 classes. It or any other model say MobileNet will always look at an image and assign probabilities to each of the 4 classes. You could put in a picture of a water buffalo and it will still try to classify it. Usually but not always if the out of class image you put in is very different from your training images the class with the highest probability will have a probability value well below 1.0. However in your case the out of class image is NOT all that different from the images in your dataset hence a fairly high false probability prediction.
All I can think off is if your out of class images will be generically similar to each other you could create a 5th class and train your model with the data you have plus gather some "typical" out of class images. Then train the model on these 5 classes. I made a model that classified 50 different dog breeds. It was extremely accurate. I put in a picture of Donald Trump and he was predicted as being a chihuahua!

Comment: Okay, I was afraid of this.  I don't have enough of the odd ball pieces to train with.  Any other thoughts?  Where else can I ask this question?